# What is the correct way to use ctime in perl?

Tags: perl

I have older perl code that uses ctime(). It requires "ctime.pl". This no longer works in newer perl versions.  This is how I would use it

```
my ($currDay, $currMon, $currDate, $currTime, $currYear) = split(" ", ctime(time));
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: You'd use [localtime](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html). Or maybe [Time::localtime](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/Time/localtime.html) for a more user-friendly interface..

Comment: @Shawn, `localtime` won't produce the correct values, at least not without also using `strftime` (from the POSIX module). That said, I'm really curious why the OP wants the dow and the month in English short form instead of numerical form.

Comment: If you go down that route, the core [Time::Piece](https://perldoc.pl/Time::Piece) provides a handy combination of localtime and strftime (plus individual accessors).

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
use POSIX 'ctime';
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was easy.